# R package building : what is the best solution to use large and external data that need to be regularly updated?

Tags: r, database, package, geocoding

We are creating a package on R whose main function is to geocode addresses in Belgium (= transform a "number-street-postcode" string into X-Y spatial coordinates). To do this, we need several data files, namely all buildings with their geographical coordinates in Belgium, as well as municipal boundary data containing geometries.

We face two problems in creating this package:

1. The files take up space: about 300-400Mb in total. This size is a problem, because we want to eventually put this package on CRAN. A solution we found on Stackoverflow is to create another package only for the data, and to host this package elsewhere. But there is then a second problem that arises (see next point).
2. Some of the files we use are files produced by public authorities. These files are publicly available for download and they are updated weekly. We have created a function that downloads the data if the data on the computer is more than one week old, and transforms it for the geocoding function (we have created a specific structure to optimize the processing). We are new to package creation, but from what we understand, it is not possible to update data every week if it is originally contained in the package (maybe we are wrong?). It would be possible to create a weekly update of the package, but this would be very tedious for us. Instead, we want the user to be able to update the data whenever he wants, and for the data to persist.

So we are wondering what is the best solution regarding this data issue for our package. In summary, here is what we want:

- Find a user-friendly way to download the data and use it with the package.
- That the user can update the data whenever he wants with a function of the package, and that this data persists on the computer.

We found an example that could work: it is the Rpostal package, which also relies on large external data (https://github.com/Datactuariat/Rpostal). The author found the solution to install the data outside the package, and to specify the directory where they are located each time a function is used. It is then necessary to define `libpostal_path` as argument in the functions, so that it works.

However, we wonder if there is a solution to store the files in a directory internal to R or to our package, so we don't have to define this directory in the functions. Would it be possible, for example, to download these files into the package directory, without the user having the choice, so that we can know their path in any case and without the user having to mention it?

Are we on the right track or do you think there is a better solution for us?